# wxGrid and right click row info

Tags: row, right-click, wxgrid

I have a wxGrid and with right click choosing Row message... item i want to take the row and col of cell.
When press right click no cell or row selecting.
With code bellow i take 1378932544. How must tell to give me the row or column?

```
 void myFrame::on_RClick( wxGridEvent& event )
{
wxMenu* menu = new wxMenu;
menu->Append(1, _("&Row message... "));
menu->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,  wxGridEventHandler(myFrame::OnPopupClick), NULL, this);
PopupMenu(menu);
}

void myFrame::OnPopupClick(wxGridEvent& evt)
{
if(evt.GetId()==1)
{
wxPoint point = evt.GetPosition();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is required to use `menu.setClientData()` in `on_RClick()` handler, as described here:
https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxMenu#PopUp-menus